# Sets with measure 0, $\mu (G)=0$ for some set G.

Tags: measure-theory

I am relatively new to Measure theory and I am really struggling with the concept of measure. I'm interested to know how a set which isn't an empty set can have measure of 0.. that is $\mu (G)=0$ and what would be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the family of sets such that $\{G \in \Sigma : \mu (G) =0\}$. For $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ a measure space. Can someone please explain to me in noob terms please so I can finally understand this concept. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How long is a single point of $\Bbb R$? What's the volume of a sheet of paper? What's the area of a line?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, that is a good visualization but how can you even begin to construct a $\sigma$-algebra of something like this, All so abstract!

Comment: A $\sigma$ algebra is not more frightening than a topology, where you would call "measurable" anything that is either closed or open.

Comment: Measure is a generalization of length (or area  or volume). The length of a bounded real interval  with end-points $a,b$  is $|a-b|.$ So the length of the (degenerate) interval $\{a\}=[a,a]$  is $0$.The Lebesgue measure of the  union of a finite set of  bounded, pair-wise disjoint  intervals is the sum of their lengths.  So the Lebesgue measure of any finite subset of $\Bbb R$ is $0$. For a countably-additive measure, the measure of a countable union of  null (measure-$0$) sets is null. So any countable subset of $\Bbb R$ is Lebegue-null.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu$ is countably additive then $H=\mu^{-1}\{0\}=\{G: \mu(G)=0\}$ is closed under countable unions and countable intersections. (That is if $J\subset H$ and $J$ is countable then $\cup J\in H$ and $\cap J\in H$.)

A $\sigma$-algebra $S$ on $X$ such that $S\supset H$ must satisfy $S\supset H^*=\{X\setminus G: G\in H\}.$

If $\mu$ is countably additive then $H\cup H^*$  $is$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $H.$